# How to update repository with built project?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I’m trying to set up GitLab CI/CD for an old client-side project that makes use of Grunt (https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular).

Up to now the deployment worked like this:

- run ’$ grunt build’ locally which built the project and created files in a ‘dist’ folder in the root of the project
- commit changes
- changes pulled onto production server

After creating the .gitlab-ci.yml and making a commit, the GitLab CI/CD job passes but the files in the ‘dist’ folder in the repository are not updated. If I define an artifact, I will get the changed files in the download.  However I would prefer the files in ‘dist’ folder in the to be updated so we can carry on with the same workflow which suits us. Is this achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think commiting into your repo inside a pipeline is a good idea. Version control wouldn't be as clear, some people have automatic pipeline trigger when their repo is pushed, that'd trigger a loop of pipelines.

Instead, you might reorganize your environment to use Docker, there are numerous reasons for using Docker in a professional and development environments. To name just a few: that'd enable you to save the freshly built project into a registry and reuse it whenever needed right with the version you require and with the desired `/dist` inside. So that you can easily run it in multiple places, scale it, manage it etc.

If you changed to Docker you wouldn't actually have to do a thing in order to have the `dist` persistent, just push the image to the registry after the build is done.

**But to actually answer your question:**

There is a feature request hanging for a very long time for the same problem you asked about: [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/18106). Currently there is no safe and professional way to do it as GitLab members state. Although you can push back changes as one of the GitLab members suggested (*Kamil Trzciński*):

```
git push http://gitlab.com/group/project.git HEAD:my-branch
```

Just put it in your `script` section inside `gitlab-ci` file.
There are more hack'y methods presented there, but be sure to acknowledge risks that come with them (pipelines are more error prone and if configured in a wrong way, they might for example publish some confidential information and trigger an infinite pipelines loop to name a few).

I hope you found this useful.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. It looks like we need to adjust our workflow and/or make use of Docker. Cheers.

Comment: So, it'd be nice if you accepted my answer if it helped ;)